# invalid syntax when run cProfile

Tags: python, ipython, profile, cprofile

I tries to run `python -m cProfile simple_test_script.py`. I'm on Windows 7, Python 2.7.10.

simple_test_script.py:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eigvals

def run_experiment(niter=100):
    K = 100
    results = []
    for _ in xrange(niter):
        mat = np.random.randn(K, K)
        max_eigenvalue = np.abs(eigvals(mat)).max()
        results.append(max_eigenvalue)
    return results
some_results = run_experiment()
print 'Largest one we saw: %s' % np.max(some_results)
```

I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-6634cb53f497>", line 1
    python -m cProfile simple_test_script.py
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I read this documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

> (Use profile instead of cProfile if the latter is not available on
>   your system.)

I tried profile instead of cProfile but the the same error. Any clues how i can call cProfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As satoru suggested, you would normally run a command like this in your shell/terminal/console (for everyday usage, these basically mean the same thing). However, you *can* also run it from inside IPython, e.g.:

```
%run -m cProfile simple_test_script.py
```

(the % symbol is part of the command, IPython has a few special commands that start with %)

Comment: Thank you! That worked excellent. %run -m cProfile simple_test_script.py

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you were running the following command inside IPython:

```
python -m cProfile simple_test_script.py
```

You should just run it in your shell.

Comment: Thank you @satoru! I would like to run it inside IPython. but thanks for the great explanation why got the error.